# How to get hours and minutes by subtracting two dates with R

Tags: r, date, format

I have two columns in R and both of them are dates with the following format..

```
   1/2/2015 3:00:00 PM
```

I need to create a new column which is 'Hours' which would be the amount of hours have passed between the two dates. I've tried this but it gives me the difference in days..

```
col1 <- df$collection.when
col2 <- df$discardable_when
col3 <- as.Date(col1) - as.Date(col2)
head(col3)
# > Time differences in days
[1] -393   NA   NA   NA -485   NA
```

EDIT:

It seems that @HubertL answer would be the correct solution, however I cannot get complete a data.frame for an unknown reason.. heres a screenshot that shows my workflow. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: rstudio]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `as.Date`, use `as.POSIXct` which includes time information.

You can also use `difftime` to specify units of output.

```
time1 = as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 01:00:00")
time2 = as.POSIXct("2015-03-02 05:00:00 PM")

difftime(time2, time1, units = "min")
Time difference of 86640 mins
```

Comment: I thought about this, however it doesn't accept the format the data is currently in.. How would Ii remove the AM or PM from the columns of data ? @Señor O

Comment: Add the format specifier to POSIXct argument. `as.POSIXct("1/2/2015 3:00:00 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Date`s don't have time.

You probably could use POSIXct :

```
a <- as.POSIXct(strptime("1/2/2015 2:00:00 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), tz="")
b <- as.POSIXct(strptime("1/2/2015 5:00:00 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), tz="")
c <- b - a; 
units(c) <- "hours"
as.numeric(c)
[1] 3
```

Comment: I feel as like this solution should work, but it gives me unexpected results, please check out the edit

Comment: I noticed the dates work when its a clean time.. "1/2/2015 5:00:00 PM" but if its "1/2/2015 5:11:011 PM" the code breaks? can you explain that for me..